# High CPU - NT Kernel & System, Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit

Tags: windows, windows-8, cpu, kernel

I have 64-bit Windows 8.1 Pro, Lenovo X220. All updates are installed (both Windows and from Lenovo Solution Center).

Every time my computer starts, one of the processes uses 25% of CPU (until computer is restarted). Task manager says it is "NT Kernel & System".

I did not find anything useful when googling (except "update windows, update drivers"). For a while I thought I can use kernview and Process Explorer - unfortunately, Kernrate Viewer is not available for Windows 8 as far as I can see.

Windows installation is quite new, antivirus updated (Syamantec), no malware detected (AdwCleaner, MalwareBytes)

How do I find what is starting this process and why it has such high CPU usage?

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I did:

- download [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)
- show properties of NT Kernel & System and go to Threads tab
- locate high CPU thread (in my case it was risdx64.sys)
- show DLL view in Process Explorer and locate risdx64.sys - it is  RICOH PCIe SDXC/MMC Controller Driver
- uninstall driver

Now, card reader is not working, but CPU usage is OK.

Comment: Nicely diagnosed. :)

Comment: You saved my butt !!
Display driver was doing the same in my PC, and I discovered that by the steps you mentioned.

Thanks a lot.